# NHibernate OneToMany Mapping By Code

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

I saw many exemple on the internet on Mapping relation object with nhibernate but i can't make mine works.

I have two Model for exemple:

```
public class Vehicule
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual int Color { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserModel User { get; set; }
}

public class VehiculeMap: ClassMapping<Vehicule>
{
    public VehiculeMap()
    {
        Table("G1Vehicule");

        Id(x => x.Id, map => { map.Column("id"); });
        Property(x => x.Brand, map => { map.Column("brand"); });
        Property(x => x.Color, map => { map.Column("color"); });
        Property(x => x.UserID, map => { map.Column("user_id"); });
    }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Username { get; set; }

}

public class UserModelMap : ClassMapping<UserModel>
{
    public UserModelMap()
    {
        Table("Users");

        Id(x => x.Id, map => { map.Column("id"); });
        Property(x => x.Username, map => { map.Column("username"); });
    }
}
```

Previously, I only displayed the UserId, but now I would like to fill my UserModel when I get a specific VehiculeModel from the database.

Here my Model relation is OneToOne.
Also for design purpose I will never query an User to get his list of vehicule, so I dont need to have a "List of VehiculeModel" in my UserModel.

If you have any hint, about how I can map this in my Map class (saw a lots of xml mapping but i would like to map it by code) It would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the documention, unfortunately I already read them but it didnt help me. Also I made a mistake, it's a OneToOne relation I updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it work. 
nothing to complicate in fact, I just forgot to add my second model (UserModelMap) in the map class list for Nhibernate.

```
public class VehiculeMap: ClassMapping<Vehicule>
{
    public VehiculeMap()
    {
        Table("G1Vehicule");

        Id(x => x.Id, map => { map.Column("id"); });
        Property(x => x.Brand, map => { map.Column("brand"); });
        Property(x => x.Color, map => { map.Column("color"); });
        Property(x => x.UserID, map => { map.Column("user_id"); });

        ManyToOne(x => x.User, map => {
            map.Column("user_id"),
            map.Fetch(FetchKind.Join),
            map.notFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore)
        })
    }
}
```

Maybe it could help someone else.